# function with a recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I have this recursive equation:

$$\begin{align*}
F(m,n)&=F(m,n-1)+F(m-1,n)-F(m-1,n-1-m)\\\\
F(m,0)&=F\left(m,\frac12m(m+1)\right)=1\\
F(m,i)&=0\text{ if }i<0\text{ or }i>\frac12m(m+1)
\end{align*}$$

is there a way to solve this recursive equation to get a close form for $F(m,n)$

I have tried z transform, but I got nothing